Is a file with two extensions idiomatic if it is metadata related to another existing file?
I have a program which generates and caches JSON metadata for files of multiple media types (e.g. .jpeg, .png). Is it idiomatic to include the original file extension in the name of the metadata file to demonstrate how they are related and avoid naming collisions where there are two media files with the same name but different extensions (e.g. my_photo.jpeg.json, my_photo.png.json)?

"Idiomatic" might be too strong word here, especially in a Windows environment. But it's not uncommon, and there's nothing wrong with it (even on Windows).

There's also https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fork_(file_system) if you're fine with its various limitations

@Someprogrammerdude works for me, I guess I would only ever find use for it when it comes to quick and dirty scripts anyways like I am now

@Martheen thanks for the link, that's some great information
